# Uploading multiple images doesn't work when I try to upload a medium resolution image

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

The limit for the upload is 10 MB but when I try to upload a 120 KB image it doesn't work. It works perfectly when I upload a 10 KB image, only when it's like 100 kB it cancels the upload and it doesn't work at all.

This is the code

```
  <body>
    <!--Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">AcquaSpare</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Condizioni</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prodotti</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ricambi</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" role="search" action="lista_prodotti.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="ricerca" class="form-control" placeholder="Ricerca Prodotto">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Invio</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php
              session_start();
              require 'config.php';
              require 'connect.php';
              list($id, $nome, $prezzo, $descrizione, $disponibili, $codice)=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id AS id, nome, prezzo, descrizione, disponibili, codice FROM prodotti WHERE id='".$_SESSION['prodid']."'"));

              if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id AS id, username FROM utenti WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'"));
                echo 'Benvenuto, <strong>',$row['username'],'</strong>';
              }else{
                echo 'Il Mio Account';
              }

              ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>      Carrello</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>      Profilo</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <?php
                  if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                    echo '<li><a href="close_session.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>      Logout</a></li>';
                  }else{
                    echo '<li><a href="login.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>      Login</a></li>';
                  }
                  ?>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav><!--Of navbar -->
    <div class="container">
      <div id="ctn1">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="aggiungi_immagini.php">
          <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
            <span>Seleziona Immagini</span>
            <input id="uploadBtn" class="upload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
          </div>
          <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Nessun File selezionato" disabled="disabled" /><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Carica" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form><br>
        <?php
        $valid_formats = array("gif","jpg","jpeg","png","wbmp","bmp","webp","xbm","xpm");
        $max_file_size = 80*1024^2; //10 MB
        $path = "images/".$_SESSION['prodid']."/"; // Upload directory
        $count = 1;
        $picid=$id;
        if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
            // Ripeto per ogni file caricato
          ?><div id="ctnmultiimages" style="heigth:300px;"><?php
            foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
                if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                    continue; // Salto se ci sono stati errori
                }
                if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
                    if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                        $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                        continue; // Salto per i formati troppo grandi
                    }
                    elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                        $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                        continue; // Salto per i formati non validi
                    }
                    else{ // Nessun errore, sposta i file
                    $kaboom = explode(".", $name); // Split file name into an array using the dot
                    $fileExt = end($kaboom);
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], "images/".$id."/".$name)){
                    $count++;
                }
                }
            }

        }
        }
        $files = array();
        foreach (new DirectoryIterator('images/'.$_SESSION['prodid'].'/') as $fileInfo) {
            if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
            $files[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
        }
        foreach ($files as $filename) {

        ?>
          <style>
            #imagelisticon{
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
              position: absolute;
              margin-left:-100px;
              z-index: 2;
              background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
              line-height: 200px;
              height: 200px;
              width:200px;
              font-size: 40px;
            }
            #imgcnt{
              background-size: cover;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              position:relative;
              margin-top:40px;
              width:200px;
              height:200px;
              display: inline-block;
              border: 1px solid lightgrey;
              line-height: 198px;
              overflow: hidden;
            }
            .trash{
              position: absolute;
              vertical-align: text-top;
              margin-top: 5px;
              margin-left: 50px;
              z-index:3;
            }
          </style>
            <div id="imgcnt" style="background-image: url('images/<?php echo $id;?>/<?php echo $filename;?>');">
              <div id="<?php echo $filename;?>" class="btn btn-danger trash"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
              <i id="imagelisticon" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?></div><br>
          <center><a href="modifica_prodotto.php"><div class="btn btn-success">
          Conferma
        </div></a></center><?php



    ?>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
$("DIV[class='btn btn-danger trash']").click(function(){
  var delfile = ($(this).attr("id"))
  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: {
            source1: delfile
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
    location.reload()
})



</script>
```

This is the upload part

```
<?php
    $valid_formats = array("gif","jpg","jpeg","png","wbmp","bmp","webp","xbm","xpm");
    $max_file_size = 80*1024^2; //10 MB
    $path = "images/".$_SESSION['prodid']."/"; // Upload directory
    $count = 1;
    $picid=$id;
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        // Repeat for each uploaded file
      ?><div id="ctnmultiimages" style="heigth:300px;"><?php
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                continue; // Skip if there are errors
            }
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Skip for too large file
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Skip for not valid formats
                }
                else{ // no errors, move files
                $kaboom = explode(".", $name); // Split file name into an array using the dot
                $fileExt = end($kaboom);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], "images/".$id."/".$name)){
                $count++;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: check max_upload_size variable in your php.ini file

Comment: I can't access to the php.ini file because of the hosting website, but the max upload size is 64 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

$max_file_size was equal to

```
$max_file_size=80*1024^2 //10 MB
```

That should be 10 MegaBytes.

Because I didn't really know what to do I tried replacing that value with the operation done:

```
$max_file_size=83886080 //Still 10 MB
```

I really don't know why it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP configuration for:

- `post-max-size` - http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
- `upload-max-filesize` - http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

If both look ok, then post the error message or have a look how exactly is the request canceled (what status code, etc.)

Comment: The problem is that it gives no error message... I cannot have the access to the php.ini file but the max upload size is 64 MB

Comment: Then check log files for your virtual host. If it ends with error you should see something there.